# What is new command in Java8 from "jmap -heap <PID "

Tags: java-8

What is command in Java8 for jmap heap .I need to find Oldgen space of Memory for particular process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Java 8, We can use below command to get current stats of Heap Memory consumption for all the blocks.

jcmd PID PerfCounter.print

Which is basically the alternative to jmap -heap

Answer (score 1):

if you want to create a heapdump with jmap, the command is:

```
jmap -dump:live,fle=/path/to/file/name.bin,format=b <pid>
```